# Where should the subtitle setting be in video games?

Tags: accessibility, games, settings

I was recently playing *Dead Space 3* and was trying to turn on the subtitles.  I found them to be in the Audio sub-menu.  In other games, it can be in the Game or Video sub-menus.

As subtitles are part Audio setting and part Video setting, where should subtitle settings really be located?

Comment: It can also appear like with DVD menus under language options. I think that location is apt.

Comment: Sometimes it's in the Audio tab, sometimes in general game options where it's most visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most video games I have played I find the subtitle setting is in the audio sub menu as it relates most to the audio in the game i.e. you want to read what people are saying.

The video sub menu is more concerned with the game graphics and UI.

Answer (score 4):

It should always go in 'audio'. Subtitles are not part video / part audio, the subtitle setting is purely a setting for how the audio in the game is treated.

Answer (score 1):

*The Walking Dead* has a menu called Audiovisual, if I recall. I'm a fan of games like *Metal Gear Solid 4* that put all options in a single menu with similar options in tabs or some other grouping.

To answer TC, I think that subtitles are conventionally considered audio options but ideally there shouldn't be any distinction between audio and video options.